# ruby: validate input before appending to array

Tags: ruby, arrays, validation

I have a ruby class that has an Array as one of its instance variables. I'm trying to figure out how to validate data that is being pushed onto the array.

```
class Something
  def things
    @things ||= Array.new
  end
end
```

So I can declare an instance and add stuff to the array pretty easily this way.

```
@s = Something.new
@s.things << "one"
@s.things << "two"
```

I tried to create a class method named `things<<(inString)` to handle the validation but that is not valid syntax. So what approach can I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
class MyThings < Array
  def << (item)
    # do your validation with item
    self.push(item) if item.valid?
  end
end

class Something
  def things(item)
    @things ||= MyThings.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
things << data if valid?(data)
```

where `valid?` is your validation method.

Example:

```
...
# will push only when quantity is greater than 0
def push(quantity)
  things << item if valid?(quantity)
end

private
  def valid?(number)
    number > 0
  end
```

If you want to have you own `ThingsArray` just create an `Array` subclass and override the push (`<<`) method to make the validation before pushing:

```
class ThingsArray < Array
  def << (item)
    return unless valid?(item)
    super
  end

  private

  def valid?(item)
    item > 0
  end
end

class Something
  def things
    @things ||= ThingsArray.new
  end
end
```